# Show $ \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n-\ln(n)}=\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{\ln(n)}{n^{2}} \right) $

Tags: asymptotics, taylor-expansion

> I would like to show that :
>   $$ \dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{n-\ln(n)}=\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{n}+\mathcal{O}\left(\dfrac{\ln(n)}{n^{2}} \right) $$
>   by starting from the left side and get the right side

My proof:

> note that :

- $$\left( 1+x \right)^{\alpha}=1+\alpha x+\mathcal{O}\left( x^2\right) $$
- $$ \dfrac{\ln(n)}{n}\underset{ \overset { n \rightarrow +\infty } {} } {\longrightarrow}0$$

> 

\begin{align*}
\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{n-\ln(n)}&=\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{n}\left(1-\dfrac{\ln(n)}{n} \right)^{-1} \\
&=\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{n}\left(1+\dfrac{\ln(n)}{n}+\mathcal{O}\left(\dfrac{\ln^2(n)}{n^2} \right) \right) \\
&=\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{n}+\dfrac{(-1)^{n}\ln(n)}{n^2}+\mathcal{O}\left(\dfrac{\ln^2(n)}{n^3} \right) \\
&=\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{n}+\mathcal{O}\left(\dfrac{\ln(n)}{n^{2}} \right) \\
\end{align*}

Since : $$\dfrac{(-1)^{n}\ln(n)}{n^2}+\mathcal{O}\left(\dfrac{\ln^2(n)}{n^3} \right)=\mathcal{O}\left(\dfrac{\ln(n)}{n^{2}} \right)$$

- $$\left|\dfrac{\dfrac{(-1)^{n}\ln(n)}{n^2}}{\dfrac{\ln(n)}{n^{2}}} \right|\leq 1 \implies \dfrac{(-1)^{n}\ln(n)}{n^2}=\mathcal{O}\left(\dfrac{\ln(n)}{n^{2}} \right)$$
- $$\left|\dfrac{\dfrac{\ln^2(n)}{n^3} }{\dfrac{\ln(n)}{n^{2}}} \right|=\dfrac{\ln(n)}{n} \underset{ \overset { n \rightarrow +\infty } {} } {\longrightarrow}0 \implies \dfrac{\ln^2(n)}{n^3} =\mathcal{O}\left(\dfrac{\ln(n)}{n^{2}} \right)$$
- Is my proof correct

Comment: Correct but a bit tedious, for example, using the simpler expansion $$(1+x)^{-1}=1+o(1)$$ when $x\to0$ instead of $$(1+x)^{-1}=1-x+O(x^2)$$ saves ink and yields the answer. Striving to use the simplest limited expansions to solve each given problem is a worthy investment...

Comment: @Did i'll follow my ur advice Thank you

Comment: it should be $\frac { { \left( -1 \right)  }^{ n } }{ n-\ln { n }  } =\frac { { \left( -1 \right)  }^{ n } }{ n } { \left( 1-\frac { \ln { n }  }{ n }  \right)  }^{ -1 }$

Comment: yep it's just typo Thanks i ll fix it

Answer (score 1):

Correct, but there are unnecessary details. A shorter version is this
$$\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{n-\ln(n)}=\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{n}\cdot\dfrac1{1-\cfrac{\ln n}n}+\mathcal{O}\left(\dfrac{\ln(n)}{n^{2}} \right)$$
Now $\;\dfrac1{1-u}=1+\mathcal O(u)$, so
$$\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{n-\ln(n)}=\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{n}\biggl(1+\mathcal{O}\Bigl(\dfrac{\ln n}{n} \Bigr)\biggr)=\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{n}+\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{n}\mathcal{O}\Bigl(\dfrac{\ln n}{n} \Bigr)=\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{n}+\mathcal{O}\Bigl(\dfrac{\ln n}{n^2}\Bigr).$$

Comment: yes it's what @Did said to me

Comment: @Educ: I see that now. It seems I was writing my answer while Did was posting his/her comment.